# Manejo de Json en C# y Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, jsonobject, newtonsoft

Buen día gente.

Mi pregunta va por unas pruebas que estoy realizando en el manejo de Json con Newtonsoft en C#. En el siguiente código:

```
JObject productos =
    new JObject(
        new JProperty("nombre", "Shampoo Furia"));

JObject Categoria = new JObject(
    new JProperty("id"),
    new JProperty("nombre"));

JArray cat = new JArray();

Categoria["id"] = 1;
Categoria["nombre"] = "Aseo";
cat.Add(Categoria);

Categoria["id"] = 2;
Categoria["nombre"] = "Baño";
cat.Add(Categoria);

productos.Add(new JProperty("Categorías", cat));

Console.WriteLine(productos.ToString());
```

La salida es la siguiente:

```
{
  "nombre": "Shampoo Furia",
  "Categorías": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nombre": "Baño"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nombre": "Baño"
    }
  ]
}
```

Estoy agregando una Categoría con unas propiedades al JArray cat, luego las cambio en el objeto y lo agrego modificado. Sin embargo, se modifica también el objeto que ya había agregado.

Entonces quise probar realizando todo aquello en otro método:

```
private static JToken NuevaCategoria(int id, string nombre, JObject categoria)
{
    categoria["id"] = id;
    categoria["nombre"] = nombre;

    return categoria;
}

private static void PrintJsonTest()
{
JObject productos =
    new JObject(
        new JProperty("nombre", "Shampoo Furia"));

JObject Categoria = new JObject(
    new JProperty("id"),
    new JProperty("nombre"));

JArray cat = new JArray();

cat.Add(NuevaCategoria(1, "Aseo", Categoria));
cat.Add(NuevaCategoria(2, "Baño", Categoria));

productos.Add(new JProperty("Categorías", cat));

Console.WriteLine(productos.ToString());
}
```

Sin embargo, el resultado fue el mismo.

No quiero seguir pegando código para no alargar la cosa, pero probé realizando esto con listas y con una clase separada creando instancias y el resultado era siempre el mismo.

Agradecería vuestra ayuda para ver en qué me estoy equivocando, y espero le sirva a otro que tenga el mismo problema a futuro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu objeto:

```
JObject Categoria = new JObject(
    new JProperty("id"),
    new JProperty("nombre"));
```

Lo estas usando 2 veces, pero sigue siendo el mismo objeto, solo le cambias el valor de la propiedad. Por eso cuando llega el momento de imprimirlo, te lo imprime 2 veces con los últimos valores asignados.

Debes crear una función así:

```
private static JToken NuevaCategoria(int id, string nombre)
{
    return new JObject(
        new JProperty("id",id),
        new JProperty("nombre",nombre));

}
```

De esta manera instancias un nuevo objeto "Categoria" cada vez